# Cant Update Array With Dropdown Button And Future Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, filtering

I am using a dropdown button to update locations of restaurants around a user but, the locations aren't updating in the ListView. Here is what I have so far:

Edit: Added Init statement

Init Statement

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _dropDownMenuItems = buildAndGetDropDownMenuItems(changeDistance);
    _mapDropdownFilter = _dropDownMenuItems[0].value;
    filterMarker(userLat, userLong, dispensaries, 1);

    super.initState();


  }
```

I set up a class to assist with this called locations

```
class Locations{
  final Restaurant dis;
  final double dist;
  final int index;
  Locations({this.dis, this.dist, this.index});
}
```

Then call this filter to sort my location by distance and give them a distance in miles from user:

```
  Future filterMarker(userLat, userLong, restaurants, filterdis) async {
    Set<Marker> _tmpMarkers = Set();
    final Uint8List markerIcon =
        await getBytesFromAsset('assets/smiley.png', 100);

    int filterCounter = 0;
    List<Locations> _tmpLocation = List();
    for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.length; ++i) {
      Geolocator()
          .distanceBetween(
              userLat, userLong, restaurants[i].lat, restaurants[i].long)
          .then((calcDist) {
        print(calcDist);
        if (calcDist / 1000 < filterdis) {
          filterCounter++;
          final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$filterCounter';

          final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
          var dis = calcDist / 1000;
          var distances = dis.toStringAsFixed(2);
          // creating a new MARKER
          _tmpMarkers.add(Marker(
              markerId: markerId,
              position: LatLng(restaurants[i].lat, restaurants[i].long),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: restaurants[i].name, snippet: '$distances mi Away'),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon)));
          _tmpLocation.add(
              Locations(index: i, dis: restaurants[i], dist: calcDist / 1000));
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        _filteredMarkers = _tmpMarkers;
        filteredVenues = _tmpLocation.cast<Locations>();
      });

      print('Do once');
    }
    print('There are ${filteredVenues.length} _filteredMarkers');
  }
```

My drop down button button is setup like this:

```
DropdownButton(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
                          color: Colors.black),
                      elevation: 6,
                      icon: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.angleRight,
                        color: buddiesGreen,
                      ),
                      value: _mapDropdownFilter,
                      items: _dropDownMenuItems,
                      onChanged: _changeFilterList,
                    )
```

Filled with this:

```
//Distance Map filter Button
  final List changeDistance = ['1', '5 ', '10 ', '20'];
  // Set<Marker> _filteredMarkers = Set();
  List<Locations> filteredVenues;
  var _filteredMarkers;
  var filteredRestaurant;

    _dropDownMenuItems = buildAndGetDropDownMenuItems(changeDistance);
    _mapDropdownFilter = _dropDownMenuItems[0].value;

  String _mapDropdownFilter;
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItems;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> buildAndGetDropDownMenuItems(List tempList) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = List();
    for (String x in tempList) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          value: x,
          child: Text(
            x,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: buddiesPurple),
          )));
    }

    return items;
  }

void _changeFilterList(String value) {
    //use _filterDropdown for switch statement
    setState(() {
      _mapDropdownFilter = value;
    });
    _sortProductsDropDown(_mapDropdownFilter);

    print(_mapDropdownFilter);
  }

  void _sortProductsDropDown(_mapDropdownFilter) {
    switch (_mapDropdownFilter) {
      case '1 Mile':
        print('1 Mile');
        filterMarker(userLat, userLong, restaurant, 1);
        print(restaurant.length);
        break;
      case '5 Miles':
        filterMarker(userLat, userLong, restaurant, 5);
        print(restaurant.length);

        break;
      case '10 Miles':
        filterMarker(userLat, userLong, restaurant, 10);
        print(restaurant.length);

        break;
      case '20 Miles':
        filterMarker(userLat, userLong, restaurant, 20);
        print(restaurant.length);

        break;
    }
  }
```

It doesn't update when I hit the dropdown where is the disconnect and why doesn't it up date when the user selects different distances.

Comment: Where are you calling `buildAndGetDropDownMenuItems()`?

Comment: When the page loads. So in the init statement

Comment: Can you remove the list view code? It isn't necessary.

Comment: Also, can you add the initState method?

Comment: Adding Init Statement

Comment: I believe the `ListView` code might have been relevant. In the builder method, you get the restaurant in the `filteredVenues` list using `final resta = filteredVenues[i];`, but for the rest of the build code you are referencing some other `restaurant` variable rather than the `resta` variable you just retrieved. My guess then is that the `ListView` is updating but because you're ignoring the value from the list and instead referring to some other constant value, the updated widget looks identical to the old one. (Either that, or this is a typo that happened when copying the code.)